# Cannot insert files to Google Drive using Service Account

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I have been unable to insert to google drive using a service account. Conversely, I can download and update files from google drive with this same Service Account without any issues.
I created the service account from within a specific user's (lets call it User "X") account by going to [My Project] -> "API's and Auth" -> "Credentials" -> "Create new client ID" from the google developer console.

I then specifically went to a folder on MyDrive for User "X" and shared this folder with the Service Account email address generated from the "Create new client ID" step for OAuth2. I made sure to specify that the service account privilege was "Can Edit" for this folder.

I've been successfully able to download files from that folder, as well as update files from that folder. I assume this means that my service account has been authenticated appropriately (in which I'm getting an AccessToken successfully that has an hour to live). I've made certain that my scope is the full access scope (ie. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) as well.

All that being said, when I try to insert a new file, it fails. I've used the basic template here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Here's a code sample of the insert:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;

File body = new File();
body.Title = "Test.pdf";
body.Description = "Why doesn't this work?";
body.MimeType = "application/pdf";
body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = [ID GOES HERE] } };
using (System.IO.MemoryStream oMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            string sUploadFileFromDiskPath = @"[PATH TO FILE]";
            using (System.IO.FileStream oFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(sUploadFileFromDiskPath))
            {
                this.BufferedWriteToTarget(oFileStream, oMemoryStream);
                oFileStream.Close();
            }
            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload insertRequest = ServiceAccount.DriveService.Files.Insert(body, oMemoryStream, body.MimeType); //NOTE: "DriveService" is authenticated (has an AccessToken from the ServiceAccountCredential) in this context with full scope authority
            IUploadProgress progress = insertRequest.Upload();
            File file = insertRequest.ResponseBody; //This is "null" prior to execution because the .Upload() threw an exception
            oMemoryStream.Close();
        }
```

An exception is uccuring on the Upload() call, and I can see this exception in the IUploadProgress object. The exception says ***"The given header was not found"***. The stack trace is as follows:
`"   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload1.<UploadCoreAsync>d__e.MoveNext() in c:\\code\\google.com\\google-api-dotnet-client\\default\\Tools\\Google.Apis.Release\\bin\\Debug\\output\\default\\Src\\GoogleApis\\Apis\\[Media]\\Upload\\ResumableUpload.cs:line 459"`

Is this a bug in the API, or am I missing something that was not included in the sample?

Keep in mind, I've given the service account edit access to the folder I'm trying to upload to, so that shouldn't be a problem. I am NOT trying to impersonate the user, and don't believe in this case that I am required to.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:** I tried creating an InstalledApplication instead of a ServiceAccount. I was able to authenticate the InstalledApplication just fine (for User "X") and get my Access & Refresh Tokens, but I got this EXACT SAME ERROR in this same context!

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem was with the "BufferedWriteToTarget" method, but I'm not sure why it's causing an issue? Once I changed to use the "ReadAllBytes" method as shown in the sample, it worked fine.

Here is the code I have for the BufferedWriteToTarget:

```
    private void BufferedWriteToTarget(System.IO.Stream oSourceStream, System.IO.Stream oDestinationStream)
    {
        ////This code copies one stream into another stream.
        const int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int n;
        while ((n = oSourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            oDestinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
```

I'm going to keep the post because I think it's informative in terms of the steps I took to setup the service account (eg. I don't see any documentation anywhere else that covers how to set up a service account with rights to specific folders within a user's account).